# The meaning of a single & in an if statement

Tags: c, if-statement

Came across a weird notation today while reading through some C code
Can anyone explain to me what the line do?

```
if ((dwEvent & EV_RXCHAR) && cs.cbInQue) { /* do stuff */}
```

Comment: It masks `dwEvent` with `EV_RXCHAR`, checks if it is non-zero, checks if `cs.cbInQue` is non-zero, if both are true, executes code in conditional statement.

Comment: & is the C bitwise and operator.

Comment: Side note - the expression with the & has to be in parenthesis because C / C++ has a bad precedence for the binary operators which should have the same precedence as multiply for & and add / subtract for ^. K & R later noted it was wrong, but didn't want to fix it since it could possibly break existing code. Without the parenthesis, the & (binary and) would be evaluated after EV_RXCHAR && cs.cbInQue (logical and), which doesn't make sense.

Comment: did you read some C books before?

Answer (score 4):

```
if ((dwEvent & EV_RXCHAR) && cs.cbInQue) { /* do stuff */}
```

[`&` is Binary And Operator](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/10/bitwise-operators/). `&` is applied to every bit of both the variables .It checks ,

if result of `dwEvent & EV_RXCHAR` is `non-zero` then `cs.cbInQue` is checked if it is `non-zero` or not .
If both the conditions are true code in if block is executed .

if result of `dwEvent & EV_RXCHAR` is zero then without checking `cs.cbInQue` , code in else block is executed if present.

Answer (score 2):

It masks (performs binary AND operation) `dwEvent` with `EV_RXCHAR`, checks if the result is non-zero, checks if `cs.cbInQue` is non-zero, if both are true, executes code in conditional statement.

This is not necessarily a "weird" notation. Many programmers use it as a shortcut instead of specifying `(x & y) != 0`.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bitwise operation. You can read it here. [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C)

Answer (score 0):

Its short form to check if the any of the bits EV_RXCHAR are set by checking getting out those bits first (dwEvent & EV_RXCHAR). Then if any of these are set it
would also check if cs.cbInQue is also set then do the stuff.
eg:

```
unsigned int x = dwEvent & EV_RXCHAR;
if (x !=0)
    if (cs.cbInQue != 0)
        { /* do stuff */}
```